# Why shouldn't we use multiple activation functions in the same layer?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I'm a newbie when in comes to ML and neural nets, have been studying mainly online through coursera videos and a bit of kaggle/github. All the examples or cases where I've seen neural networks being applied have one thing in common - they use a specific type of activation function in all the nodes pertaining to a specific layer.

From what I understand, each node uses non-linear activation functions to learn about a particular pattern in the data. If it were so, why not use multiple types of activation functions?

I did find one [link](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/17298/do-all-neurons-in-a-layer-have-the-same-activation-function), which basically says that it's easier to manage a network if we use just one activation function per layer. Any other benefits?

Comment: I wouldn’t say that an activation function learns “a particular pattern”. I think the whole network learns to accomplish the task at minimal loss, and although sometimes the particular activation function is important, especially for the output layer, many times different activation functions have similar performance, so I suspect that using multiple activation functions in a single layer just wouldn’t have a benefit worth the time to code it, but I haven’t read about anyone trying that.

Comment: @Joe Not the activation function, but doesn't the node itself learn something from the patterns?

Comment: It depends. I think that if you set up a network like an autoencoder with a bottleneck layer, then you can make the case that each node in the bottleneck layer represents an independent component in some latent space, like a principal component but nonlinear. However, in general I think neural nets are often black-box models - not very interpretable, but they work.

Comment: There are sometimes when we want a particular activation function, like when we want to model a probability distribution so we use softmax for the output, and each node in the output is the probability of a particular class. However, the universal approximation theorem says that almost all Lebesgue integrable functions can be approximated arbitrarily well with a deep enough network with just ReLU activation functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Purpose of an activation function is to introduce **non-linearity** to a neural network. See this [answer](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/5510/15526) for more insight on why our deep neural networks would not actually be **deep** without non-linearity.

Activation functions do their job by controlling the outputs of the neurons. Sometimes they provide a simple threshold like ReLU does, which can be coded as following:

```
if input > 0:
    return input
else:
    return 0
```

And some other times they behave in more complicated ways such as `tanh(x)` or `sigmoid(x)`. See this [answer](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/5521/15526) for more on different sorts of activations.

I also would like to add that I agree with @Joe, an activation function does not learn a **particular pattern**, it effects the way that a neural network learns multiple patterns. Each activation function have its own kind of effect on the output.

Thus, one benefit of not using multiple activation functions in a single layer would be predictability of their effect. We know what **ReLU** or **Sigmoid** does to the **output of a convolutional filter** for example. But do we now the effect of their cascaded use? In which order btw, does **ReLU** come first, or is it better for us to use **Sigmoid** first? Does it matter?

If we want to benefit from the combination of activation functions, all of these questions (and maybe many more) need to be answer with scientific evidences. Tedious experiments and evaluations should be done to get some meaningful results. Only then we would now what does it mean to use them together and after that, maybe a new type of activation function will arise and there will be a new name for it.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the answer! 
You speak of the order of activations within a layer, how'd the order make a difference in a fully connected network?
Also, is there any suggested order in which these activations should appear in a network? As in a ReLU layer should be followed by a Sigmoid, or may be the other way around? If not, what is the best way to find out the best permutation possible (apart from brute force)?

Comment: You're most welcome. The most correct answer to that would be `I do not know`. But here is one thing to consider: Functions `f` and `g` commute if `f o g = g o f ` or `f(g(x)) = g(f(x))`. So the answer of the question "Are all activation functions commutative with each other?" might be a good place to start. More at this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1895212/524714).